# Cypress type error when given string returned from cypress command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have the following cypress command function created,

```
Cypress.Commands.add("gen_date", () => {
    var now_dt = new Date(Date.now());
    var dte =
        ("0" + now_dt.getDate()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + now_dt.getHours()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + now_dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + now_dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) +
        ("00" + now_dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
    return dte;
});
```

I call this command in the following test file ,

```
it("see if test string generated in input", () => {

    let o = cy.gen_date();

    cy.get("input[id=\"inputid\"]")
        .as("inputinput")
        .type(o)
        .type("{enter}");
```

I expect o to be a string, but instead in cypress tests I get the error, cy.type() can only accept string or number and you passed in [object, Object]

Could someone point me in the right dirction

Comment: Please check the question - `Cypress.Commands.add("gen_date"...` but `let o = generate_order_number()`

Comment: Updated, was trying to make code more readable and concise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress custom commands return a Chainable which passes the result forward to the next linked command, so you can access it by nesting

```js
cy.gen_date().then(dt => {

  cy.get("input[id=\"inputid\"]")
  .as("inputinput")
  .type(dt)
  .type("{enter}");
})
```

or use plain JS function instead of a custom command

```js
const gen_date = () => {
  var now_dt = new Date(Date.now());
  var dte = ("0" + now_dt.getDate()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getHours()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) +
            ("00" + now_dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
  return dte;
};

let o = gen_date();

cy.get("input[id=\"inputid\"]")
  .as("inputinput")
  .type(o)
  .type("{enter}");
```

---

Adding the function globally:

in `/cypress/support/index.js`

```
Cypress.gen_date = () => {
  var now_dt = new Date(Date.now());
  var dte = ("0" + now_dt.getDate()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getHours()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + now_dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) +
            ("00" + now_dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
  return dte;
};
```

in the test

```
let o = Cypress.gen_date();
```

Comment: What is the convention when I want to resuse that js function in other test files ?

Comment: I was under the impression you should not import files/functions aside from cypress commands into cypress test files

Comment: Importing the function should be fine, but you can also add it to the Cypress object provided the name does not clash with something else.

Comment: Thank you very much !